# Is there a Django/Pythonic way of keying Django querysets by a particular value of the queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have this view that I am using in Django REST API:

```
class HSKView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        hsk_levels = HSKLevels.objects.all()
        serializer = HSKSerializer(hsk_levels, many=True)
        return Response({"hsk": serializer.data})
```

And here's the serializer in case it is needed:

```
class HSKSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HSKLevels
        fields = ["level", "label", "value"]
```

It gives me the following output:

```
{
    "hsk": [
        {
            "level": 1,
            "label": "HSK 1",
            "value": "hsk1"
        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "label": "HSK 2",
            "value": "hsk2"
        },
        {
            "level": 3,
            "label": "HSK 3",
            "value": "hsk3"
        },
        {
            "level": 4,
            "label": "HSK 4",
            "value": "hsk4"
        },
        {
            "level": 5,
            "label": "HSK 5",
            "value": "hsk5"
        },
        {
            "level": 6,
            "label": "HSK 6",
            "value": "hsk6"
        },
        {
            "level": 7,
            "label": "HSK 6+",
            "value": "hsk6plus"
        }
    ]
}
```

But ideally, I'd like to have a key to each of these items, rather than just something to iterate over, so I'd most likely to prefer it to look like this:

```
{
    "hsk": {
        1: {
            "level": 1,
            "label": "HSK 1",
            "value": "hsk1"
        },
        2: {
            "level": 2,
            "label": "HSK 2",
            "value": "hsk2"
        },
        3: {
            "level": 3,
            "label": "HSK 3",
            "value": "hsk3"
        },
        4: {
            "level": 4,
            "label": "HSK 4",
            "value": "hsk4"
        },
        5: {
            "level": 5,
            "label": "HSK 5",
            "value": "hsk5"
        },
        6: {
            "level": 6,
            "label": "HSK 6",
            "value": "hsk6"
        },
        7: {
            "level": 7,
            "label": "HSK 6+",
            "value": "hsk6plus"
        }
    }
}
```

The "level" value is also the primary key.

Comment: Neither Django nor DRF does have this functionality. But, you will be able to represent the `serializer.data` in the *"required format"* with some iterations

Comment: @JPG Ok, makes sense. I wasn't sure if there was a set function to do it or if I needed to do it manually. Thanks

Comment: @StevenMatthews you can try overriding the [to_representation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/883f6fe814acdbc35032143275ae78f6ff832d82/rest_framework/serializers.py#L655-L665) method on your serializer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method-1

Override the **`to_representation(...)`** method of the serializer

```
class HSKSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HSKLevels
        fields = ["level", "label", "value"]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {rep["level"]: rep}
```

### Method-2

Iterate `serialzer.data`

```
class HSKView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request):
        hsk_levels = HSKLevels.objects.all()
        serializer = HSKSerializer(hsk_levels, many=True)
        return Response({"hsk": {data["level"]: data} for data in serializer.data})
```

Comment: Perfect! I did the representation override. I need to refresh myself on list comprehensions as well - my initial language was Python, but it's been years since I've used it extensively

Comment: One thing I am noticing is that it is still a list, not a dict at the top. Is there a way to make it a dict of dicts instead?

Comment: Oops. Then, better go with the second method.